# how to get matchit to work with % with key mapping on vim?

Tags: vim, git-bash, vim-plugin

i'm trying to get vim to select between matching html tags including the parent tags..
Following are  two mappings i tried..

```
nnoremap <leader>h <s-v><s-5>
```

or

```
nnoremap <leader>h <s-v>%
```

but nothing seems to work. the problem is '%' doesn't perform the extended(with the matchit plugin) action which is selecting the matching closing html tag..

Comment: What's wrong with `vat`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:normal!` and `:execute` to run normal commands without remapping. e.g.

```
nmap <leader>h :execute "normal! V"<cr>%
```

This command is really similar to using the "a tag block", `at`, text-object. e.g. `vat`. Of course you can do what you are doing and just execute `V%` as it is the same number of characters as `<leader>h`.

Comment: Sorry, but why the `execute normal`? Wouldn't `nmap <leader>h V%` be enough? Feels like I'm missing something important :o

Comment: Probably. I assumed you wanted `%` to remap but not `V`. If this is not the case then your mapping is fine

Comment: Ah, I see now. I knew I was missing something...sorry it is just that it didn't came out clear your intention. Just seemed to make it complicated to me initially :) I don't know what the questioner wants precisely though